# Asking user for multiple input

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to write a program which will keep asking a user for an integer until they input a value which isn't an integer, at which point the program stops.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InputStats {
    private static Scanner a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList InputArray = new ArrayList();
        Boolean Running = true;
        System.out.println("Please type an integer. To stop enter a non integer value");
        while (Running) {
            a = Scanner.nextLine();
            if (!a.hasNextInt()) {
                Running = false;
            }
            else {
                InputArray.add(input.nextLine());

        }

            System.out.println(InputArray);
        }

    }
}
```

However, with this code I am recieving the errors:

```
error: non-static method nextLine() cannot  be referenced from a static context (for the line a = Scanner.nextLine();)
```

and

```
error: incompatible types (for the line a = Scanner.nextLine();)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: There is naming convention that variable shall start with lower case characters and classes with upper case. The code is then easier to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String str = input.nextLine();
```

You don't need Scanner a at all.  Just replace all the references to it with references to `input`.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by creating a function to see if a String is numeric or not.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputStats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> inputArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Please type an integer. To stop enter a non integer value");
        boolean canContinue = true;
        String a;
        while(canContinue) {
            a = input.next();
            if(isNumeric(a) == true) {
                int b= Integer.parseInt(a);
                inputArray.add(b);
            }
            else {
                canContinue = false;
            }

        }

        System.out.println(inputArray);
        input.close();
    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        try {
            int d = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```